# Java regex identifying references to bugs in Github

Tags: java, regex, github

I need to capture all the bug numbers that are referenced from commit messages in Github.

A bug number is an integer and a reference starts with **fix** / **fixes** / **fixed** / **fixing** / **close** / **closes** / **closed** / **closing** / **resolve** / **resolves** / **resolved** / **resolving** followed by **#XYZ** which XYZ is the bug number.

Here's an example and what I have tried:

```
String commitMessage = "This fixes #23 fixed#24 fix #25, #26 resolves #27 #28#29 resolved#30 #31 ,  #32. Also see #33";
String regex = "clos(e|es|ed|ing) ?#[0-9]+" 
        + "|fix(es|ed|ing)? ?#[0-9]+" 
        + "|resolv(e|es|ed|ing) ?#[0-9]+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(commitMessage);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

and the output is:

```
fixes #23
fixed #24
fix #25
resolves #27
resolves#30
```

But I need it to be:

```
fixes #23
fixed #24
fix #25, #26
resolves #27 #28#29
resolved#30 #31 ,  #32
```

Note that the references may be to a single bug (e.g., #23) or multiple bugs at the same time (e.g., #25, #26).

Also note that when referencing to multiple bugs, there may be one or more space and/or comma between different bug numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the `[\s\p{P}]*` to the regex before `#` to match either whitespaces or punctuation, 0 or more occurrences, and also you may contract the pattern a bit:

```
String regex = "(?:(?:clos|resolv)(?:e|es|ed|ing)|fix(?:es|ed|ing)?)(?:[\\s\\p{P}]*#[0-9]+)+";
```

The main difference is `(?:[\\s\\p{P}]*#[0-9]+)+` that matches 1 or more occurrences of:

- `[\\s\\p{P}]*` - 0+ whitespace or punctuation characters
- `#` - a hash symbol
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/EphoWP):

```
String commitMessage = "This fixes #23 fixed#24 fix #25, #26 resolves #27 #28#29 resolved#30 #31 ,  #32. Also see #33";
String regex = "(?:(?:clos|resolv)(?:e|es|ed|ing)|fix(?:es|ed|ing)?)(?:[\\s\\p{P}]*#[0-9]+)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(commitMessage);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
fixes #23
fixed#24
fix #25, #26
resolves #27 #28#29
resolved#30 #31 ,  #32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follow regex:

```
clos(e|es|ed|ing)([ ,]*#[0-9]+)+ ?|fix(es|ed|ing)?([ ,]*#[0-9]+)+ ?|resolv(e|es|ed|ing)([ ,]*#[0-9]+)+ ?
```

Here is a working example:
https://regex101.com/r/In7cox/1

Answer (score 1):

I would use two sets of regex (and two `while` loop).  I would also use named-capture groups to make the code more readable and easier to maintain:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GitHubBugTrackingRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String commitMessage = "This fixes #23 fixed#24 fix #25, #26 "
                + "resolves #27 #28#29 resolved#30 #31 ,  #32. Also see #33";
        String regexBugReference    = "(?<oneBug>#\\d+)"; 
        String regexBugReferences   = "(?<someBugs>(\\s*,*\\s*" + regexBugReference + "\\s*)+)"; 
        String regex = 
                "(?<oneCase>(?<resolution>clos(e|es|ed|ing)|fix(|es|ed|ing)|resolv(e|es|ed|ing))"   
                        + regexBugReferences
                        + ")";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commitMessage);
        while (m.find()){
            String resolution   = m.group("resolution");
            String someBugs     = m.group("someBugs");
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(regexBugReference);
            Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(someBugs);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String comma = "";      // first time special
            while (m2.find()) {
                String oneBug = m2.group("oneBug");
                sb.append(comma + oneBug);
                comma = ", ";       // second time and onwards
            }
            System.out.format("%8s %s%n", resolution, sb.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

The output of this code was:

```
   fixes #23
   fixed #24
     fix #25, #26
resolves #27, #28, #29
resolved #30, #31, #32
```

Comment: This is a nice solution that separates single and multiple references.